# Can Spark streaming and Spark applications be run within the same YARN cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

Hello people and happy new year ;) !

I am bulding a lambda architecture with Apache Spark, HDFS and Elastichsearch.
In the following picture, here what I am trying to do:
[image]

So far, I have written the source code in java for my spark streaming and spark applications. I read in the spark documentation that spark can be run in a Mesos or YARN clutser. As indicated in the picture, I have already a hadoop cluster. Is it possible to run my spark streaming and spark application within the same hadoop cluster ? If yes, is there any particular configuration to do (for instance the number of nodes, RAM...). Or do I have to add a hadoop cluster specialy for spark streaming ?

I hope my explanation is clear.

Yassir

Comment: Yes, you can. Please check: https://www.inovex.de/blog/247-spark-streaming-on-yarn-in-production/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not build a separate cluster for running spark streaming.

Change the `spark.master` property to `yarn-client` or `yarn-cluster` in `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file. When specified so, the spark application submitted will be handled by the ApplicationMaster of YARN and will be executed by NodeManagers.

Additionally modify these properties of *cores* and *memory* to align Spark with Yarn.

In `spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.executors.memory
spark.executors.cores
spark.executors.instances
```

In `yarn-site.xml`

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores
```

Else it could lead to either deadlock or improper resource utilization of the cluster.

Refer [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) for resource management of cluster when running Spark on Yarn.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You submit your streaming and batch applications to same yarn cluster. But sharing of cluster resources between these two jobs could be a bit tricky(as per my understanding).

So I would suggest you to look at [Spark Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) to submit your applications. The Spark-jobserver makes your life easier when you want to maintain multiple spark contexts. All the required configurations for both the applications will be at one place.